# Change the value of aobject based on other array of object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have below kind of object

```
sampleObject = {name : 'John' , age : 34 }
```

I want to update the age value based on the below array of object value:

```
sampleArrayOfObject = [{name:'John',age:20},{name:'Mathew',age:23},{name:'Mohammed',age:20}]
```

The final Output that I want is

```
updatedOject = {name:'John',age:20}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share that as a text-based [mcve]. Consider looking at [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sampleObject = {name : 'John', age : 34 }
const sampleArrayOfObject = [{name:'John',age:20}]
const updatedOject = {...sampleObject, age: sampleArrayOfObject[0].age}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you want the operation to be done, but here is one of the options:

```js
function update(obj, objs) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    age: objs.find(v => v.name === obj.name)?.age ?? obj.age,
  };
}

let updatedOject = update(sampleObject, sampleArrayOfObject);
```

Here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGBbADgGwKYHkBGArdwsAvDAN5hLowBcMA5AFIgAWYdMANDPAOZW0BmACwwAvgG4AUJNCRYCFBgCCAJxXwAnpgBmOfIRgkA2uUrVGLNh17pqAJgAMojqcS26AWXhRm6AO501nz2As6u7h4sSG4AJoE29k4AulKS2gCuYIQAluAw6cgx3ugAFCB4XOW4EACUZJIwMCroUOkqYPWNjQB0vVUcDV0JMFUQ3drZYDElAG6GAHwwM90UboZEJFUrlDUA-N02MLu7I3gHfAONEpLXkhiwBUVQ6DGY%20sT5hcUlCmhYeAQoFxfso1JodHpATUpLIICAMN1UCAeCVHsVXu9oUA) for this option, and here is what you get when if you click "Run":

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 20
}
```

Here is the same option but with proper typings:

```js
type Person = { name: string; age: number }

function update(obj: Person, objs: Person[]): Person {
  return {
    ...obj,
    age: objs.find(v => v.name === obj.name)?.age ?? obj.age,
  };
};
```

And this is the same code but with generics (I'd say a preferred approach, but don't take this for granted):

```js
function update<T extends { name: string; age: number }>(obj: T, objs: T[]): T {
  return {
    ...obj,
    age: objs.find(v => v.name === obj.name)?.age ?? obj.age,
  };
};
```